# Concise way to call ifilter with multiple predicates in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator

I'm streaming a very large collection through a script and am currently using `ifilter` in a simple call to reject certain values, i.e.:

```
ifilter(lambda x: x in accept_list, read_records(filename))
```

That's one predicate, but now it's occurred to me I should add another, and I might want to add others in the future. The straightforward way would've been nesting an `ifilter` call:

```
ifilter(lambda x : x not in block_list,
    ifilter(lambda x: x in accept_list, read_records(filename)))
```

I am thinking of simply putting the predicates as unbound functions in a list and using them for this. These repeated ifilter calls seem hard to attain there though (and might not be the best option). Perhaps I can construct a single function that calls all the predicates but how do I write this as concisely (while still readable) as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write the following function:

```
def conjoin(*fns):
    def conjoined(x):
        for fn in fns:
            if not fn(x): return False
        return True
    return conjoined
```

You would then call it like so:

```
ifilter(conjoined(lambda x: x not in block_list, lambda x: x in accept_list),
        read_records(filename))
```

And you could implement a similar `disjoin` function for *or*-ing functions together:

```
def disjoin(*fns):
    def disjoined(x):
        for fn in fns:
            if fn(x): return True
        return False
    return disjoined
```

There may be a nicer way to implement them, but one has to be careful.  One might try applying every function to `x` and using `all` or `any`, but this is undesirable, since using them will require evaluating every predicate on the argument.  The solution presented here is satisfactorily short-circuiting.

Also, just for fun, let's implement an `invert` function

```
def invert(fn):
    return lambda x: not fn(x)
```

Now, we have a [functionally complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) set of function-manipulating functions, and can construct any logical operation out of these :)

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the following solution:

```
def complex_predicate(x):
    return x not in block_list and x in accept_list and is_good(x)
```

or

```
def complex_predicate2(x):
    return all([x not in block_list, x in accept_list, is_good(x)])
```

and then

```
ifilter(complex_predicate, read_records(filename))
```

or the same with `complex_predicate2`.

But, I think it is a matter of taste, though.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two predicates, I would come up with the following:

```
ifilter(lambda x: x in accept_list and x not in block_list, read_records(filename))
```

Also, as it was mentioned above, if there are more than two predicates, it's better to put all the predicates in the specific function.
Using `all` makes the condition block much less messy (because all predicates get separated by comma in this case).